# OCaml: fold_left, fold_right conversion

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

In http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html, 
we have:

`val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`

`List.fold_left f a [b1; ...; bn] is f (... (f (f a b1) b2) ...) bn`.

`val fold_right : ('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b -> 'b`

`List.fold_right f [a1; ...; an] b is f a1 (f a2 (... (f an b) ...))`. Not tail-recursive.

The question is how to implement "fold_left" function using the List.fold_right function.
And this is the answer I found in the internet:

```
let rec my_fold_left f a l = List.fold_right (fun x g a -> g (f a x)) l (fun x -> x) a;;

val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
```

In the first time, I write:

```
let rec my_fold_left_old f a l = List.fold_right (fun x a -> f a x) l a;;

val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
```

the type check is right, but the my_fold_left_old is wrong because it scan the list from the last element to the first element.

Can anyone explain the function my_fold_left above, the List.fold_right can have only 3 arguments, but the my_fold_left above has 4 arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currying. Essentially, `List.fold_right` has a type of `('a -> 'b -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b`, and this definition uses that operation with a *function type* for `'b`.

You can see how this can produce "four arguments" for `List.fold_right` if you substitute `'c -> 'd` for `'b`, skipping redundant parens:

```
('a -> 'c -> 'd -> ('c -> 'd)) -> 'a list -> 'c -> 'd
```

So the `List.fold_right` folds over the list to produce *a function*, which is applied to one argument to produce the final result. To make that clearer, let's rewrite it with a named temporary:

```
 let foldl f init list =
  let fold_result =
    List.fold_right
      (fun elt g acc -> g (f acc elt))
      list
      (fun x -> x) in
  fold_result init
```